# Modify TastyPie resource queryset with information in filters

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a situation where I want to modify a Resource's queryset based on the filters that are being passed in.

I want this because certain filters require expensive operations to be added to the queryset, and I want to only do them if the user requests the filter in question.

The documentation ([HERE](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset)) shows you how to modify the queryset using `get_object_list` (which has access to the request).

I want to do something like:

class MyResource(ModelResource):

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    current_qs = super(MyResource, self).get_object_list(request)
    current_filters = SOMEHOW_GET_FILTERS(request)

    if 'name' in current_filters:
        current_qs = current_qs.annotate(best_friend=RawSQL("COMPLICATED SQL QUERY"))

    return current_qs
```

Any thoughts? If I could do a build_filters from get_object_list without interrupting the rest of the request/response cycle, that might solve my problem. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone comes along with a better answer, but:
I inspected the `request` object, and found it has a request['GET'] field that stores the `queryDict`.

So, if you call `localhost:8000/api/dosomething?first_name=stevie&last_name=wonder`

Then `request['GET'].keys()` will return `['first_name,' 'last_name']`

For my purposes, that was enough. You might want to pass that to `self.build_filters`, but I didn't need to.